# Is it possible to distribute a selling app as free for a limited time on Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

#### Background

Google Play users really tend not to buy apps, despite their likely quality, so it would be a great thing to distribute your app as free for a certain period during which people experience your app, verify that it would worth an eventual cost, write appreciative reviews and rumor positively about it. And if this optimistic forecast is not totally fulfilled, at least you have raised the indicator of the number of downloads.

Another good way to make users pass the barrier of the "billing fear" would be to send a limited number of codes of which each one can be used once to download your app for free. You would then distribute these codes to the layers of the user population that could like it and hope that they trigger the download flow.

About inserting ads in the application, I have to say that I find application with ads really annoying and ugly-looking and that I think that if you want people to like your app, you first have to like it yourself. Furthermore, I believe that my content is very good and doesn't deserve to be clouded by showy ads.

About offering in-app purchases, also that option wouldn't fit my project since I'm developing a touristic guide, a sort virtual book lacking of a hierarchical layout (so what would I block and why? It would be like taking away some entries of an encyclopedia).

#### Question

If you developed and Android app and you plan on selling it, is it possible to distribute it for free on Google Play for a limited time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Android Developer's Launch Checklist](http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/launch-checklist.html#decide-price):

> Deciding whether you apps will be free or paid is important because,
>   on Google Play, **free apps must remain free**.
>
> - Once you publish an app as a free app, you cannot change it to being a priced app. However, you can still sell in-app products and
>     subscriptions through Google Play's In-app Billing service.
> - If you publish your app as a priced app, you can change it at any time to be a free app (but cannot then change it back to priced). You
>     can also sell in-app products and subscriptions.

So, without looking at the alternatives: No, you cannot set the price free for limited time. Another consideration is to put a donate button/link somewhere in the app.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly, but what you can do is put it out for free, declaring clearly in the description that it's a trial version.  Then do an in-app purchase to unlock it permanently.

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is possible now, either by creating [Promo Codes](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6321495?hl=en), or creating [Sales](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7271135#guidelines) for decreasing price of app. You can make it free with second option, at least for 1 day and at most for 7 days.